# How I can keep the all dynamically duplicated form element after form submission?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I am working on a registration system using php. I have a form that contains user information and Certifications information. The user could click on "Add another certificate" link which will dynamically duplicate the field set of certificate information with all form input elements using the code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

        var i = 1;

        function duplicate() {
            var original = document.getElementById('certificateInfo1'); // id of first fieldset 
            var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
            clone.id = "certificateInfo" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID

            var beforeEle = document.getElementById("addNew");    // Get the <p> element to insert the div before it a
            original.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, beforeEle);

        }
    </script>
```

The problems that I faced are:
1- When the form is submitted and there is error message, the dynamically created `<fieldset>` and its children is disappear. How I can keep the all dynamically created field set with its children ?

2- How can I get the data of each certificate alone to insert it in the database? because all form element will have the same name.

Comment: 1. I would think, based on the number of `certificateInfo` fields that were submitted, you could pass that same information back to your javascript to repopulate the form. 2. it appears you're giving each field a unique ID, so they won't have the same name.

Comment: 1-How I could achieve that? because when the form is submitted and there some errors the page is refreshed and all dynamically created elements is removed.     2- no I'm giving an ID only for the <fieldset> element. But its children will have the same name as its original ones, so in the $_POST how I could get the data of each certificate alone?

Comment: @mistermartin is right, it can be achieved by repopulating the dynamically created element. But, there's an "easier" way: submit the form using ajax so the page will not refresh. The problem about ajax is that of course, it depends on javascript. If you don't want the ajax solution, I will try to answer your question when I have time.

Comment: Thank you. I used Ajax and the problem is solved. Thanx.